# Generic Aws client builder with Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm working on a project that now we have a request to give all the instances(Ec2,S3, etc...) the option to make the coll thought a proxy server.
For example, I have:

```
AmazonElasticLoadBalancing elbClient = AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClientBuilder.standard()       .withRegion(region.getName()).withCredentials(credentials).build();

AmazonEC2 ec2Client = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).withCredentials(getCredentials()).build();
```

In a lot of places in my project.

After checking AWS Java SDK docs I saw that I need to add `withClientConfiguration(someMethodToGetProxyConfig())` before using `build()`.

I'm still kind of new to java and I'm having a hard time creating a function that generic enough to do this for all these kinds of clients.
I've tried:

```
public static AwsClientBuilder clientBuilder(AwsClientBuilder client) throws ServiceWareException {
        final String PROXY = "proxy_host_port";
        String hasProxy = Configuration.getConfigurationParameter(PROXY);
        client = client.withRegion(getRegion()).withCredentials(getCredentials());
        if (!hasProxy.isEmpty() && hasProxy != null)
            client = client.withClientConfiguration(getProxyConfig());
        return (AwsClientBuilder) client.build();

    }
```

But it failed because I cant cast AmazonEC2ClientBuilder to AwsClientBuilder.
Can someone maybe share some tips on how to do it or maybe had experience doing something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last line, you're calling `.build()`, which returns a client rather than a client *builder*. If you remove that call to `.build()` then I imagine the code will work.

```java
public static AwsClientBuilder clientBuilder(AwsClientBuilder client) throws ServiceWareException {
    final String PROXY = "proxy_host_port";
    String hasProxy = Configuration.getConfigurationParameter(PROXY);
    client = client.withRegion(getRegion()).withCredentials(getCredentials());
    if (!hasProxy.isEmpty() && hasProxy != null)
        client = client.withClientConfiguration(getProxyConfig());
    return client;
}
```

If you want to use this, you need to call `.build` on the result. In order for that to typecheck nicely you probably also want to add generic type parameters to the signature (so `.build` returns a value of the right type).

```java
public static <S extends AwsClientBuilder<S, T>, T> AwsClientBuilder<S, T> clientBuilder(AwsClientBuilder<S, T> client) throws ServiceWareException {
    ...
}
```

If you want this method to actually build the client, you can call `.build` within the method, but then it needs to return a client, rather than a client builder. Since this is a different behaviour, I've changed the name of the method to reflect that.

```java
public static <S extends AwsClientBuilder<S, T>, T> T buildClient(AwsClientBuilder<S, T> client) throws ServiceWareException {
    final String PROXY = "proxy_host_port";
    String hasProxy = Configuration.getConfigurationParameter(PROXY);
    client = client.withRegion(getRegion()).withCredentials(getCredentials());
    if (!hasProxy.isEmpty() && hasProxy != null)
        client = client.withClientConfiguration(getProxyConfig());
    return client.build();
}
```

Comment: I wish I could do more than one upvote, thank you so much, that helped me a lot and also help me understand generics more :)